# Can I pass a string variable to jq not the file?

Tags: json, bash, variables, input, jq

I want to convert JSON string into an array in bash.
The JSON string is passed to the bash script as an argument (it doesn't exist in a file).

Is there a way of achieving it without using some temp files?

Similarly to this:

```
script.sh

#! /bin/bash
json_data='{"key":"value"}'
jq '.key' $json_data

jq: error: Could not open file {key:value}: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 183, accepted):

I would suggest using a bash [here string](https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html).  e.g.

```
jq '.key' <<< "$json_data"
```

Comment: How would I use two strings instead of two files so I can use `jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1 file2` ?

Comment: @KatieS: Use a new bash variable to concatenate the two strings, then pass that.

Comment: and how do you pipe the results of that into something else?

Comment: Perhaps `jq '.key' <<< "$json_data" | something else`

Comment: I think this one is an easier to understand syntax: `echo "$json_data" | jq '.key'`

Answer (score 40):

The value of the variable "json_data" that was given in the original question was not valid JSON, so this response still covers both cases (nearly-valid and valid JSON).

#### Valid JSON

If "$json_data" does hold a valid JSON value, then here are two alternatives not mentioned elsewhere on this page.

#### `--argjson`

For example:

```
 jq -n --argjson data "$json_data" '$data.key'
```

#### `env`

If the shell variable is not aleady an environment variable:

```
json_data="$json_data" jq -n 'env.json_data | fromjson.key'
```

#### Nearly-valid JSON

If indeed $json_data is **invalid** as JSON but valid as a jq expression, then you could adopt the tactic illustrated by the following transcript:

```
$ json_data='{key:"value"}'
$ jq -n "$json_data" | jq .key
"value"
```

Comment: I meant the 'key' to be the string type. Should probably have used the 'name' word instead.

Comment: Anyways both examples worked for me (bash on mac), even with quoted "key" and produced similar results to the here string from the jq170727's solution.

Comment: For anyone else who doesn't need the key search: it's just `jq -n $json_data`. So simple, but both the docs and online examples are super unclear for such a simple scenario. They all seem to assume you want to do something complicated.

Answer (score 23):

Use the bash: `echo "$json_data" | jq '.key'`

Answer (score 12):

Absolutely. Just tell bash to [give it a file instead](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

```
jq '.key' <(echo "$json_data")
```

And make sure you run it in bash, not sh.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use inline command, I found this work on my Mac:

```
echo '{"key":"value"}' | jq .key
```

Comment: Store the result in a variable to use in later stages. Say your json is already in a variable and you need the result in another one.

`jsonData="{"key":"value"}"
result=$(echo $jsonData | jq -r '.key')`

echo $result will produce value as result.

Answer (score 5):

```
#! /bin/bash
json_data='{"key":"value"}'
echo $json_data | jq --raw-output '.key'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do this in a `.sh` file, this is what worked for me:

```
local json_data $(getJiraIssue "$1")               # store JSON in var
echo `jq -n "$json_data" | jq '.fields.summary'`   # pass that JSON var to jq
```

Answer (score -2):

Just do

```
$ jq '.key' <<< $'{"key":"value"}'
"value"
```

Comment: I donwvoted because this [doesn’t](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/584784/48415) work in some shells due to `<<<`.