# JQ filter returns 'false' when key is not hardcoded

Tags: json, jq

When using JQ to test the value of a key, the filter is unexpectantly returning `false` when it expected to instead return `true`.

Assume the following variables -

```
TAGS='{"kubernetes.io/cluster/my-cluster":"owned"}
CLUSTER_NAME="my-cluster"
```

When testing `$TAGS` using a hardcoded value the filter returns `true`, as expected.

```
echo $TAGS | jq '."kubernetes.io/cluster/my-cluster" == "owned"'
```

However, after introducing `clusterName` as a JQ argument, the filter now returns `false`.

```
echo $TAGS | jq --arg clusterName $CLUSTER_NAME '."kubernetes.io/cluster/" + $clusterName == "owned"'
```

I first wondered if the `-` in the `$CLUSTER_NAME` was the issue, but removing that (and updating `$TAGS` to match) yields the same result.

I've tried the following in the filter, all of which also yield the same result.

```
."kubernetes.io/cluster/" + "$clusterName"
."kubernetes.io/cluster/ + $clusterName"
."kubernetes.io/cluster/$clusterName"
```

How can the filter be amended to work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string interpolation (`\()`) <sup>[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example69)</sup> to concat that variable to the rest like so:

```
'."kubernetes.io/cluster/\($clusterName)" == "owned"'
```

```
echo $TAGS | jq --arg clusterName $CLUSTER_NAME '."kubernetes.io/cluster/\($clusterName)" == "owned"'
```

Shows `true` when testing with the supplied variables.

---

That said, I'd recommend using here-string (`<<<`) instead off `echo |` like so:

```sh
$ TAGS='{"kubernetes.io/cluster/my-cluster":"owned"}'
$ CLUSTER_NAME="my-cluster"
$
$ jq --arg clusterName $CLUSTER_NAME '."kubernetes.io/cluster/\($clusterName)" == "owned"' <<< "$TAGS"
true
$
```

<sup>[Can I pass a string variable to jq not the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105490/can-i-pass-a-string-variable-to-jq-not-the-file)</sup>

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize `clusterName`? This missing initialization is also odd in the OP's code.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean by initialize `clusterName`. It's defined in BASH and inported to jq using --arg

Comment: In your code, I see only an assignment to `CLUSTER_NAME`, but not to `clusterName`. Of course, if `clusterName` is an envrionment variable set in the parent process, you are fine.

Comment: `--arg clusterName $CLUSTER_NAME` sets `CLUSTER_NAME` to the JQ's `clusterName`. Thats fine right?

Comment: Ah, I missed the single quotes. Now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: @0stone0 - Many thanks, that appears to have done the trick.